# Does the Android NDK support locales?

Tags: android, locale

All I really want to do is format a date using `strftime("%x")` in the right order. On most platforms a call to `setlocale("")` is enough. On Android I keep getting !@#$ US dates.

So, does Android not support locales?

Comment: 10 years and a multitude of more computation and memory power later for Android Devices,  does it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `setlocale()` and `strftime()` does not work in Android NDK, except if en_US layout is what you want.

I get the local language from the Java part by:

```
pLocaleData->pLocaleLanguage = new Locale("en").getDefault().getLanguage();
```

And the ANSI C `localeconv()` does not work in Android NDK:

```
struct lconv *localeconv(void);
```

Also the standard Unix way of getting user name, does not work in Android.

```
char *p = getenv("USER");
```

So you need to use the Java side to get the locale information.

```
String LocaleCountry = new Locale("en").getDefault().getCountry();
String LocaleLanguage = new Locale("en").getDefault().getLanguage();
String LocaleCurrency = new DecimalFormatSymbols().getCurrency().toString();
String LocaleShortDateTimePattern =new SimpleDateFormat().toPattern();
char LocaleDecimalSeparator = new DecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator();
char LocaleThousandSeparator = new DecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator();
String LocaleThousandGrouping = 
        String.format("%d;0", new DecimalFormat().getMaximumFractionDigits());
String LocaleNegativePrefix = new DecimalFormat().getNegativePrefix();
String LocaleNegativeSuffix =new DecimalFormat().getNegativeSuffix();
String Operator = Utils.getQwnername(context);
```

Comment: Looks to be a major Android Java/Android implementation (phones) bug on the thousand separator issue. The = new DecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator(); generates 0xa0 (ISO/IEC 8859-1 NBSP, not a UTF8) instead of 0x20 space separator for ISO standard/Germany-Sweden etc (non-US) thousand grouping. This causes the Java code to crash if used. To be used the 0xa0 has to be changed to 0x20 in the Java code after reading 0xa0 = new DecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator(); See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374466/replace-grouping-separator-of-decimalformat-in-formatted-value.

Comment: Is this answer still valid in 2022 ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57313) the answer is No.

> There is no support for locales in the C library / from native code, and this is intentional.
>   As Elliot pointed out, your only hope is to use JNI to get relevant values.