# Replace grouping separator of DecimalFormat in formatted value

Tags: java, bigdecimal, decimalformat

I've used `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");` to format a `BigDecimal`.

Now, I want to use that formatted value (say it is '1 250,00') to create `new BigDecimal`. I've tried this:

```
BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(model.getValue().replace(",",".").replace(" ",""));
```

But that `space` between 1 and 2 in 1 250.00 is not replaced. How can I fix it?

Example:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
BigDecimal example = new BigDecimal("1250");
String str = df.format(example);
System.out.println(str.replace(",",".").replace(" ",""));
```

Comment: You may have a different kind of whitespace. Try with `replaceAll("\\s+", "")` instead.

Comment: Tried your code, for `String  s ="1 250,00"` it works fine. So problem isn't with replace method

Comment: @Tunaki, I've put an example. Try it. My localization is Moscow/Russia, if it helps. output - 1 250. 00

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) Javadoc specifies that the symbol `,` is the grouping separator. By default, for your locale, this separator is *not* a space but a non-breaking space. This can be shown by the following code:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.forLanguageTag("ru-RU"));
System.out.println((int) symbols.getGroupingSeparator());
```

You will see that the `int` printed is 160, which corresponds to ["Non-breaking space"](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/charset/iso160-191.html) in ISO-8859-1.

To remove that character, we can use its [Unicode representation](http://unicode-table.com/en/00A0/) and replace that:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
String str = df.format(new BigDecimal("1250"));
System.out.println(str.replace(",", ".").replace("\u00A0", ""));
```

For a more general solution, not depending on the current locale, we could retrieve the grouping separator and use that directly:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
String groupingSeparator = String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator());
String str = df.format(new BigDecimal("1250"));
System.out.println(str.replace(",", ".").replace(groupingSeparator, ""));
```

Answer (score 7):

You can set *grouping separator (e.g. thousand separator)* character in your pattern by using `DecimalFormatSymbols`. It looks that in your locale it is non-breaking space so try to set it to normal space like

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');//simple space

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00", symbols);

BigDecimal example = new BigDecimal("1250");
String str = df.format(example);
```

Now your formatter will use simple space so you will be able to replace it with your code

```
System.out.println(str.replace(",", ".").replaceAll(" ", ""));
```

Output: `1250.00`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `parse` method from your `DecimalFormat` object.

```
df.setParseBigDecimal(true);    
BigDecimal bigDecimal = (BigDecimal) df.parse(model.getValue());
```

Take a look at the selected answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231802/how-can-i-parse-a-string-to-bigdecimal).

Comment: `df.parse(str)` may return other type than `BigInteger` for instance it can return `Long`. You may want to change your solution to something like `new BigDecimal(df.parse(model.getValue()).toString());`

Comment: If the number is formatted and parsed with the same `DecimalFormat` object, it should work.

Comment: Not necessarily. `df.parse(df.format(BigDecimal.ONE)).getClass()` returns `class java.lang.Long` to me.

Comment: Actually now I see that your original solution was better because it can avoiding loss of precision in case of double values. All you need to add is `df.setParseBigDecimal(true);` to ensure that all `df.parse` calls will return `BigDecimal`.

Comment: It is also mentioned in the SO question I linked to, but thanks for explicitly pointing it out (even to me).

Answer (score 2):

In your format

```
new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
```

the symbol `,` is meant for grouping separator. After removing the symbol `,` from your format you get the output **1250.00** (without grouping separator in your case *space*).

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####.00");
BigDecimal example = new BigDecimal("1250");
String str = df.format(example);
System.out.println(str.replace(",",".").replace(" ",""));
```

> Output: 1250.00

There is alternative (**2nd**) solution and it works without altering your format "#**,**###.00". Use [.setGroupingSize(0)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setGroupingSize(int)) from DecimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
df.setGroupingSize(0);
BigDecimal example = new BigDecimal("1250");
String str = df.format(example);
System.out.println(str);
```

> Output: 1250.00

Comment: But I should use ',' for decorative purposes

Comment: with .setGroupingSize(0) you might keep , in your format.

Comment: Method of which class is that?)

Comment: It is a method of the DecimalFormat (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setGroupingSize(int) ). You declare DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00"); and then do `df.setGroupingSize(0);` to set the option of decimal format.

Comment: df.setGroupingSize(0); doesn't work, i.e. no thousands separator